# setup of volume using double integrals

Tags: integration

So i have to setup a double integral for the volume of a solid under $z = 3x^2 +y^2$ and over the region bounded by $y = -x$ and $y = x^2 -6$

- I tried equating y so that left me with $x^2 +x -6=0$ which is a parabola, would that mean that the volume of the region i'm looking is for a plane??
- How would i set the boundaries for the integrals?? any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundaries for $x$ will be given by the solutions to the equation $x^2+x-6$.  The boundaries for $y$ will be given for the equations and the order of the boundaries can be seen by looking at the graphs  of $y=-x$ and $y=x^2-6$ in the region where $x$ is varying over.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh thank you so much